# How to save a selected option to a variable/session/cookie in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a select tag in rails and i want to save the selected option so i can use it as a hidden_field value in multiple forms.

I had no luck with cookies/session.

All ideas are welcome :).

For example, is this possible?

```
<%= select_tag(session[:selected], options_for_select(...)) %>
```

And then in multiple forms i ll have something like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :time_frame, :value => session[:selected]%>
```

Comment: Can you give a code example. I don't know what you mean, are you trying to save the session/variable/cookie on using javascript or are you letting it come back to the controller before attempting to bring it to yet another form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "test", :action => "set_session") do %>
  <%= select_tag(:some_select, options_for_select(...)) %>
<% end %>
```

You will have to set value in the session in controller

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
 def set_session
   session[:selected] = params[:some_select]
 end
end
```

This value can be retrieved in other views as `session[:selected]`
This is not tested code. I posted this just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Storing in session should be pretty easy. All you have to do is

```
session[:selected] = <selected_value>
```

Please post what you have tried already

Comment: Yes, but how can i get the selected value? Can you please give me an example of a select_tag in rails, and how can i store the selected value to session[:selected?